# Effects of calling sleep functions like set_current_state()/wait_event() in a device driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

I am a little confused by how kernel module works after being loaded into kernel, mainly because of the sleep function calls.

Take a character device driver as example, I have seen code like below in read() function that tries to put a 'process' to sleep using `set_current_state()` (or sometimes, `wait_event_interruptible()` etc.):

```
set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
task = current;
for(;;)
{
    if(condition)
        break;
    schedule();
}
set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
```

While in the write function or interrupt handler, they are trying to wakeup read() by setting condition to true like this:

```
condition = true;
wake_up_process(task); // -> task was stored inside read() function
```

The questions I have are:

1. Which 'process' does `set_current_state()` or `wait_event_interruptible()` put to sleep here? Is it the user space process that calls system call read() or some kernel process that is created to map the user space process?
2. Assume this device driver access is restricted to only one process by set up atomic count in open() function,  and the device driver has no interrupt enabled, what would happen if read() calls wait_event() and there is no other process actually can wake it up? does it get stuck forever (because no interruptible)?
3. What is the difference between using `set_current_state()` and `wait_event()` APIs? I have seen different pieces of code using those functions accordingly... any preference on one over the other should I consider?

Comment: Please, leave only a single question in the question post. Having multiple unrelated questions makes your question post **too broad**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Kernel code executes in context of "kernel side" of userspace thread that issued the system call. Each userspace thread has such kernel-space counterpart. From scheduler point of view, user- and kernel- parts of the thread are the same entity, thus while kernel thread is scheduled out, user thread is as well.
2. "Interruptible" and "Non-interruptible" waits differ in way signals are handled. When process is in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state and gets a signal, system ensures it wakes from schedule() as soon as possible. After that, process itself must leave wait loop if signal_pending() returns true. In example code in question text, this is not implemented properly unless 'condition' is an expression containing signal_pending() check.
3. set_current_state() is a setter call for current process state, it just sets a flag and does not do anything else. It should only be used together with proper call to schedule().
   wait_event() is a utility that implements all tech details of waiting. Normally, drivers use wait_event*() flavors, direct use of set_current_state() and schedule() are needed only in special cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it indeed clarified most of my doubts.